# pulling href after getting elements

Tags: excel, vba, href

Hopefully a really easy easy question but this is something I always seem to run into issues when web scraping.

I'm webscraping from a database containing many chemical dossiers, some of which have a separate section for toxicological information and some do not. In this example the url provided is fixed as I know this does contain a link to the toxicological info and so will pull the "Sub" url from.

I wish to check if the website has this info by pulling this ur, and if not running conditional code to give a message saying no tox info etc..

Inspecting the page:

`<li id="SubNav7_1" class="active"> <a href="/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1"> Toxicological Summary</a> </li>`

I have navigated correctly to SubNav7 but I run into a runtime error 13 when trying to get the url.

```
Public Sub GetContents()
    
'Start ECHA Search via XML HTTP Request
    
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    
'GetLink
    
    Set link = HTMLDoc.getElementById("SubNav7_1").getAttribute("href")
    
    Debug.Print link


End Sub
```

The expected output is `https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1`

If anyone could point how I can essentially get to the a tag attribute under SubNav7_1 that'd be great

Comment: Does `HTMLDoc.getElementById("SubNav7_1").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href` works?

Comment: @RaymondWu Its an improvement! `HTMLDoc.getElementById("SubNav7_1").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)` Does at least print something however I get `about:/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1` which unfortunately isn't openable as a url.

Comment: `document.querySelector("li[id='SubNav7_1']").firstChild.nextElementSibling.href` should work too. There's likely a more direct way to access it though.

Comment: @Nick - In my experience, href obtained from this method of getting HTML (via XMLHTTP request) will return relative link in that format. You will have to remove "about:" and concatenate the website root yourself (i.e. `https://echa.europa.eu`)

Answer (score 1):

When you print the whole website, you will notice that the href attribute you're looking for is not in the SubNav7_1 element. It's in a  element inside it:

```
<li id="SubNav7_1"> 
<a href="/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460/7/1"> Toxicological Summary</a> 
</li>
```

Therefore, you're getting an error accessing "href" attribute of the "li" element, because such an attribute does not exist.

If you're wondering, here's how I modified your code to see what's going on in the site you're scraping (and how I got the HTML shown above):

```
'Start ECHA Search via XML HTTP Request 
Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15460", False
XMLReq.send
 
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

'GetLink
Dim link As String
Debug.Print Mid(HTMLDoc.body.outerHTML, InStr(1, HTMLDoc.body.outerHTML, "SubNav7_1"), 150)
link = HTMLDoc.getElementById("SubNav7_1").getAttribute("href")
Debug.Print link
```